# Auto-generate conanfile.txt

Tags: conan

Is there a way to auto-generate the conanfile.txt based on the CMakeLists I already have and let it resolve the REQUIREMENT and GENERATOR dependencies?
Since the CMakeLists I have (which are in several layers) already have the dependencies, this sound like something doable.

I did browse around and couldn't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: No, but you can write an extension command that is able to do it: https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/extensions/custom_commands.html. As real example, you can take a look in https://github.com/conan-io/conan-extensions repository.

Comment: It is unlikely, however, that all ``find_package()`` contains the version to use, if there is no version, then the command will have to guess or use any random version. It sounds it is not worth the effort, and manually collecting the dependencies and writing your own ``conanfile`` is not a big deal, it will take just a couple of minutes.